# Вызов python-скрипта из php (проблемы с кодировкой)

Tags: php, python, кодировка, utf-8

Из php вызывал bash-скрипт, и все было хорошо

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
    ob_end_flush();
    system ("sudo /path/start.sh $name_user 2>&1");
```

Скрипт выполнялся на стороне сервера без проблем, но долго.

Переписал его на python'e, скрипт из консоли отлично работает и отображает  русские буквы.

Но если его вызывать из php:

```
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );
<code>
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
echo "<pre>";
system ("sudo /path/start.py $name_user 2>&1");
```

То вываливается ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/path/start.py", line 250, in 
>       print ("\u041f\u043e\u0435\u0445\u0430\u043b\u0438 )")
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)

Ошибка напервом встречающемся принте с русскими символами.

В баш скрипте, в начале, прописывал принудительно, что локаль UTF, так как не смотря на header переменные идут не как планировалось, но тут ошибка даже до переменных. Даже если все передаваемые переменные приводить к латинским символам, ругается именно на русские слова в самом скрипте.

Как поступить и как указать принудительно кодировку?

Скрипт пробовал на python2  с # -*- coding: utf -*- (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-)

Так же взял python3, который с русскими буквами уже нормально, все равно проблема остается. При этом из консоли все отлично  работает.

Конечно, есть желаение переписать весь php на python, но тем не менее, вопрос остается и проблема пока не решилась.

Как быть?

Добавлено позднее:

Что-то пока что не получается добиться результата, может не туда смотрю и не то делаю?

но добавил PYTHONIOENCODING в глобальное окружение /etc/profile

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"
```

Сам файл сделал с таким содержанием

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf -*-

import os

#print("Русский текст весь")
print(os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'])
```

При вызове из php

```
system ("sudo /path/start.py 2>&1");
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/vpn.py", line 7, in print(os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING']) File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/os.py", line 633, in getitem raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'PYTHONIOENCODING'
```

Тот же результат если

```
system ("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 && sudo /path/start.py 2>&1");
```

Это третий питон, а если второй питон, то проблем с русскими буквами теперь нет.

Получается, как и писали выше, что питон3 берет свою кодировку, но при ятном указании utf-8 все равно не использует ее?

Добавлено:

Так же попробовал такой код

```
envname = "PYTHONIOENCODING"
print("{}:\t{}".format(envname, os.environ.get(envname)))

for set_locale in [False]:
    print("locale({}):\t{}".format(set_locale,
                                               locale.getpreferredencoding(set_locale)))

for streamname in "stdout stderr stdin".split():
    stream = getattr(sys, streamname)
    print("device({}):\t{}".format(streamname,
                               os.device_encoding(stream.fileno())))
    print("{}.encoding:\t{}".format(streamname, stream.encoding))

for set_locale in [False, True]:
    print("locale({}):\t{}".format(set_locale,
                                           locale.getpreferredencoding(set_locale)))
```

вывод в консоли получил

```
PYTHONIOENCODING:   UTF-8
locale(False):  UTF-8
device(stdout): UTF-8
stdout.encoding:    UTF-8
device(stderr): UTF-8
stderr.encoding:    UTF-8
device(stdin):  UTF-8
stdin.encoding: UTF-8
locale(False):  UTF-8
locale(True):   UTF-8
Поехали )
```

А избраузера

```
PYTHONIOENCODING:   None
locale(False):  ANSI_X3.4-1968
device(stdout): None
stdout.encoding:    ANSI_X3.4-1968
device(stderr): None
stderr.encoding:    ANSI_X3.4-1968
device(stdin):  None
stdin.encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
locale(False):  ANSI_X3.4-1968
locale(True):   ANSI_X3.4-1968
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/vpn.py", line 261, in 
    print ("\u041f\u043e\u0435\u0445\u0430\u043b\u0438 )")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

То есть Кодировка ни как не передается

Попробовал добавить

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write((" Русский ").encode('utf8'))
```

И в браузере ошибки нет и русский текст появиллся... но не писать же там для каждого встречающегося предолжения?

Comment: Для начала стОит показать скрипт на пайтоне, в особенности строку 250. Там вы точно со строкой unicode работаете?

Comment: Вот так строка  - print ("Поехали )")... но  как говорил, или нет ... пробовал включать coding: utf , и писать u'-перед текстом и  name.unicode -  как то при передаче именно из php  в python  кодировка страдает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вывод скрипта перенаправлен, то нужно установить `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменную окружения:

```
$ python -c "print(u'\N{EURO SIGN}')" >output.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

vs:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c "print(u'\N{EURO SIGN}')" >output.txt # bash
```

`output.txt` содержит `€` символ, закодированный используя utf-8 кодировку.

По умолчанию, Питон 3 использует кодировку из локали (LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, LANG), если вывод перенаправлен:

```
$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)" | cat
UTF-8
$ python3 -c "import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))" | cat
UTF-8
```

Локаль по умолчанию (поломанные или вообще отсутствующие настройки) подразумевает ascii кодировку (С, POSIX). Поэтому при запуске init-скриптов (сервисы), при заходе по ssh, в cron-скриптах, если необходимо выводить символы вне ascii диапазона, то следует utf-8 локаль выбрать, например, такую как `C.UTF-8` (если она доступна на системе) или явно указать `PYTHONIOENCODING` даже на Python 3. В Python3.7+ где реализованы [PEP-538, PEP-540](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-538-legacy-c-locale-coercion), ситуация улучшилась и UTF-8 используется для ввода/вывода, если локаль C, POSIX, без необходимости указывания `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменной окружения.

В Питоне 2 кодировка при перенаправлении вообще не определена и поэтому используется `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, которая всегда должна быть ascii на Питоне 2. Если вывод идёт не на экран, то следует явно `PYTHONIOENCODING` установить.

Чтобы установить `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменную окружения прямо в команде, если `sudo` используется (`sudo` может не сохранять окружение из родительского процесса), можно использовать `sudo VAR=value command` синтакс:

```
sudo PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 /path/to/start.py
```

полностью окружение можно сохранить, если это необходимо, используя:

```
sudo -E /path/to/start.py
```

по соображениям безопасности это команда не для всех пользователей работает.

Comment: Спасибо. за ответ. Попробовал PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c "print(u'\N{EURO SIGN}')" >output.txt - если в консоле все отлично, как и вообще в консоли с русскими буквами, если  то же самое из php - то создается пустой файл (права на запуск есть). Локаль у меня вся UTF-8 (да же LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8). $python3.4 -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"  выводит UTF-8
$python3.4 -c "import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))" выводит UTF-8. если  использовать 2Питон и ставить sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") - то ругается на первый русский символ в крипте.

Comment: @Трезвый: не используйте `sys.setdefaulencoding()`. Я вижу, что Вы `sudo` используете: проверьте, что необходимые переменные окружения установлены, например, попробуйте `sudo -E` (для отладки). Очевидно также, что окружение, в котором исполняется `php` скрипт, может отличаться от окружения, которое используется для интерактивного пользователя (когда Вы за клавиатурой сидите). Проверьте значение: `os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING']` внутри Питон скрипта, когда он из php вызывается.

Comment: Создал для этого дела пустой новый файл с текстом по-русски. И 2 питон нормально его обрабатывает, а 3 нет. Вот вывод os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] ---- Русский текст весь
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/vpn.py", line 7, in 
    os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING']
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONIOENCODING'  и то же самое для 3 питона

Comment: точней, нет такой переменной окружения, так понимаю. ее на до все таки создать ?)))

Comment: @Трезвый: да, создайте (можно потренироваться на переменной `A` и shell-скиптом: `echo =$A=`).  На будущее: помещайте сообщения об ошибках в вопрос (чтобы форматирование сохранить) с  соответствующим кодом, который её вызвал, с описанием, что ожидалось получить и что происходит по шагам (словами).

Comment: Хорошо, ,, Переменная такая была и из консоли она нормльно вызывается, а вот из php нет. Так думаю. что это связано что в консоли у меня один пользователь, а php  это apche  пользователь и скорей всего он просто незнает об этой переменной окружения

Comment: @Трезвый: сравните `A=utf-8 sudo sh -c 'echo =$A='` и `sudo A=utf-8 sh -c 'echo =$A='`, если вторая команда не печатает `=utf-8=` то задайте отдельный вопрос: *"Как установить переменную окружения для команды, запускаемой из php-скрипта, через `sudo`."* (оставляя за рамками обсуждение разумности запуска `sudo` с веб-страницы).

Comment: sudo -  не разумно - согласен полностью) Если запускать A=utf-8 через судо. то первый вариант не показывает ничего. второй показывает utf-8,  если запускать все без судо. то  оба вварианта отображают utf-8

Comment: даже пробовал system ("export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 && sudo /path/start.py  2>&1");  так же  ругается, что не находит переменную окружения PYTHONIOENCODING

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29619/discussion-between-jfs-and-).

Comment: Давайте, просто код показывать в чате не удобно и непонятно ...