# Как вывести в консоль русские символы c выполняемой программы на python?

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8, консоль, unicode

Система ubuntu 16.04
Вывод команды `print` выдает `\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9`.

Comment: Версия питона какая?

Comment: версия питона 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы напечатать произвольный текст, используйте `unicode` тип:

```
print(u'\u0439')
```

То что вы видите `\xd0\xb9` в выводе Питон программы говорит, что вы пытаетесь [напечатать текстовое представление коллекции (такой как список, словарь в Питоне) или другого составного объекта, содержащего *байты*, а не `unicode` тип](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521481/23044):

```
#XXX DO NOT DO IT
print [u'\u0439'.encode('utf-8')] # a bytestring in a list
# -> ['\xd0\xb9']
```

`print(list_)` в Питоне печатает элементы списка, вызывая `repr()` функцию для каждого отдельного элемента, аналог: `print("[%s]" % ", ".join(map(repr, list_)))`. Подобное текстовое представление хорошо для отладки: оно призвано быть однозначным (во многих случаях `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`). См. [Чем отличается `__repr__` от `__str__`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534446/23044) Чтобы избежать вызова `repr()`, форматируйте вашу коллекцию вручную.

Чтобы получить человекочитаемый текст, декодируйте байты в том месте где вы их получаете (на границе с внешним миром), где у вас больше информации об их кодировке и передавайте текст внутри программы как `unicode` тип. Кодируйте текст обратно в байты, используя подходящее представление, только когда необходимо отдать данные (записать на диск, отправить по сети). Это так называемая концепция Unicode sandwich: "decode early, encode late, use Unicode inside".

Обратите внимание, что хотя попытка напечатать байты напрямую может иногда работать, но это может сломаться как только окружение изменится. К примеру, если вы напечатаете байты, которые представляют текст, закодированный в cp1251 кодировке, в окружении ожидающем cp866 кодировку, то вы можете получить [кракозябы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044). Используйте Юникод для работы с текстом в Питоне. Более строгое отношение к смешиванию Unicode текста и байт—это одно из ключевых отличий Python 3 по сравнению с Python 2.

Бывают исключения, когда вашей программе приходится много работать с путями на *nix системе в Питоне 2, тогда удобно рассматривать пути как непрозрачные куки и получать/передавать их обратно системе как есть в виде байт. См. [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)

[При перенаправлении стандартного вывода в файл или канал (pipe) или если окружение не настроено (`LC_ALL=C`), вы можете получить `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii'..` ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454056/23044). В этом случае можно установить `PYTHONIOENCODING` переменную окружения, чтобы явно задать кодировку ввода/вывода:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c 'print(u"\u0439")' > output.txt
```

См. подробнее в [Python 3.4 и русские символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/387249/23044).

На Windows, может быть полезен win-unicode-console пакет. См. [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044)

---

Если вы хотите печатать *в тексте самой Питон-программы* русские буквы, тогда на Python 2, необходимо явно декларировать используемую кодировку наверху `.py` файла; и чтобы не приходилось использовать `u''` префикс для создания строк из констант (`''`) в тексте программы, можно включить `unicode_literals`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
print('Здравствуй, мир!')
```

Обе опции можно опустить на Питоне 3 (по умолчанию всё работает).

Обратите внимание, что `coding: utf-8`  (кодировка исходного кода) не имеет никакого отношения к кодировке ввода/вывода—это независимые вещи.

Comment: спасибо, Вы мне помогли

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'фыва'.encode()
print(s)
print(s.decode())
```

out:

```
b'\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0'
фыва
```

Comment: у автора Питон 2. У вас результаты для Питона 3.