# Некорректно отображается кириллица после применения split Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Исходный файл находится локально и имеет кодировку `utf-8`. С него мне нужно прочитать некоторые строки, после чего я разделяю их c помощью `split(',')`. Если до этого строка отображалась корректно, то после применения `split` кириллические символы отображаются некорректно. 
Код:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

def getData():

    os.chdir('../static/data/')
    print os.getcwd()
    file = open('s_kh_resursy.php')
    result = []
    for line in file:

        if (line.find("array(") >= 0 & line.find(")") >= 0):
            line = line[int(line.find("array(")) + 6: int(line.find(")"))]
            list = line.split(',')
            print line
            print list
    file.close()
    pass

getData()
```

Пример из print:

```
"пшеница", 37720, 24684, 17.7, "зерновые"
['"\xd0\xbf\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x86\xd0\xb0"', ' 37720', ' 24684', ' 17.7', ' "\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5"']
```

Как с этим бороться?

Comment: С этим не нужно бороться, это всего лишь print экранирует содержимое списка для печати в консоль, с самими строками всё в порядке

Comment: Откладывая в сторону Unicode проблемы: попробуйте настоящий парсер для php, к примеру [phply](https://github.com/viraptor/phply) (первый попавшийся в гугле).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести в консоль русские символы c выполняемой программы на python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580971/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)