# Как напечатать многострочный текст хранящийся как список в pythone3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Когда вывожу список в консоль, его показывает со скобками и без переноса строки, просто все как и написано в той строке.

```
workers = ['1. Lololosh Lololoshin \n', '2. Makentosh Makentoshin \n', '3. Dratatosh Dratatoshin \n']
print(workers)
who = input('Who are you: ')
```

Подскажите как вывести его без скобок, запятых в столбик.
Если есть вариант что б не использовать списки, а что то другое, это приветствуется

Comment: Выведите в цикле да и все.

Comment: @IgorGolovin не подскажите как?

Comment: `for worker in workers: print(worker)`

Comment: @IgorGolovin Спасибо

Comment: `print(*workers, sep='')`

Comment: `print(''.join(workers))`

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/580971/23044 (полезно знать разницу между print(text) и print(repr(text))

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, не нужно хранить порядковые номера и символы переноса строк. Их можно вставить в момент вывода.
Во-вторых, если список с именами пополняться во время исполнения не будет, то лучше хранить в кортеже:

```
workers = (
    'Lololosh Lololoshin',
    'Makentosh Makentoshin',
    'Dratatosh Dratatoshin'
)
```

А выводить в простом цикле можно:

```
for i, w in enumerate(workers, start=1):
    print('{}. {}'.format(i, w))
```

Ну или pythonic way:

```
print(*['{}. {}'.format(i, w) for i, w in enumerate(workers, start=1)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: `Ну или pythonic way:` - это не pythonic-way, это путь любителей однострочников. В реальной жизни так лучше не писать, так как такая запись читается намного хуже, чем вариант с обычным циклом.